# Invalid index 3 size is 3 in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm using a `AsyncTask` to check if a `Fragment` has been replaced. The problem comes when this error happens, since I'm not using `ArrayList`. 
The crash happens very rarely, and occurs within a `AsyncTask` in a loop.

This is the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
  Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.findFragmentById(FragmentManager.java:1446)
    at com.runator.ui.newdesign.MainActivity$WaitForChangeFragment.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1035)
    at com.runator.ui.newdesign.MainActivity$WaitForChangeFragment.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1027)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
```

And this is the code where it says that the error occurs:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    Fragment auxCurrentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(ID_FRAME_LAYOUT);

    while (auxCurrentFragment instanceof FilterNavigationFragment) {
        auxCurrentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(ID_FRAME_LAYOUT);
    }

    return "Executed";

}
```

Just me says this line: 
**auxCurrentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(ID_FRAME_LAYOUT);**

If any have idea please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember that index counting starts with index 0

Comment: I do not understand what you mean to me

Comment: I think he is pointing to the fact, that the error message states what the actual problem is: an ArrayList of size 3 is requested to return item with index 3 - which is impossible because index starts at "0". So the highest index would be "2". But that does not help you. Somehow the Fragmentmanager seems to map the ID to index 3 of an internal List of Fragments. So the error is in not updating this.

Comment: But where do you see index? I see only ID

Comment: @KonstantinsBogdanovs In the stacktrace: "Invalid index 3, size is 3"

Comment: Yep, but I'm not use any index, that's what baffles me

Comment: Is the faulting line the one inside the while-loop?

Comment: this line fail: auxCurrentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(ID_FRAME_LAYOUT);

Comment: Yes, But you do that one time outside the while-loop, and one time inside. Is the first call already throwing that exception?

Comment: I am not sure but maybe fragment's count changes during "findFragmetnById" method call because it is not in main thread.

Comment: Your best bet is to run it in a debugger and check when the variable holding the index you request changes

Comment: @KonstantinsBogdanovs I am suspecting something similar. I guess replacing a Fragment is not atomic ... and neither thread-safe.

Comment: But the strange thing is that not always fails, only rarely fails.

Comment: @Sr.Pulgarín that `strange thing` is what we call the `beauty of concurrency` :)

Comment: :) Welcome to the world of multithreading!

Comment: jajaja interesting! :)

Comment: I guess you should reconsider your design so you do not need to spin-check for fragment-replacement. (spin-check = check inside loop which is bad anyway) For example you could have the Fragments raise some kind of event when they are added ... or something alike. Haven't got enough experience with fragments to give you perfect advice.

Comment: Thanks for helping! We all found the solution! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the problem is in supportFragmentMannager:

```
 public Fragment findFragmentById(int id) {
    if (mAdded != null) {
        // First look through added fragments.
        for (int i=mAdded.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
            Fragment f = mAdded.get(i);
            if (f != null && f.mFragmentId == id) {
                return f;
            }
        }
    }
    if (mActive != null) {
        // Now for any known fragment.
        for (int i=mActive.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
            Fragment f = mActive.get(i);
            if (f != null && f.mFragmentId == id) {
                return f;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

If you call `findFragmentById`not in the main thread then fragment's count may be changed during the call. You can try to call this method in the main thread.

You can use `YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread` or either handler:

```
        new AsyncTask<Void, String, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            final int ID_FRAME_LAYOUT = 0;
            final Fragment[] auxCurrentFragment = {getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(ID_FRAME_LAYOUT)};

            while (auxCurrentFragment[0] instanceof FilterNavigationFragment) {
                YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        auxCurrentFragment[0] = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(ID_FRAME_LAYOUT);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return "Executed";
        }
    };
```

Comment: Hmm, but that would block the main thread, because he is spin-checking for the fragment to be replaced ...

Comment: Maybe you should better use thred for this purpose instead of AsyncTask

Comment: I am not sure about what you are doing maybe you can solve your problem using http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html

Comment: Im check this option :)

Comment: At the moment it works! I will continue testing more!

Comment: What works? Are you trying my solution or GlobalTreeObserver?

Comment: YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread works!! Thanks all for help me! :)